# CakePHP 3.6.14: open view in pop up window -> Call to a member function url() on null

Tags: php, cakephp, modal-dialog, popup

I am trying to open a page in a pop-up window.

I tried to achieve that like this:

```
echo $this->Html->link(__('Done'), ['onclick'=>"var openWin = window.open(
     '".$html->url(['controller' => 'Tasks','action'=>'edit', $task->id]."', '_blank',
     'toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,status=1,menubar=0,resizable=1,
      width=500,height=500');  return false;")]);
```

But I get this error:

> Call to a member function url() on null

Comment: Can you try $this->Url->build([])

Comment: @SunilKumar I tried it like this : `echo $this->Html->link(__('Done'), ['onclick'=>"var openWin = window.open('".$this->Url->build(['controller' => 'Tasks','action'=>'edit', $task->id]."', '_blank', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,status=1,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=500,height=500');  return false;")]);` but now I get this error :  
Notice (8): Array to string conversion

Comment: The `onclick` must be in the third parameter to `$this->Html->link`, not the second. You can use `'#'` for the second in the case that it shouldn't be an active link.

Comment: @GregSchmidt changed it to: `echo $this->Html->link(__('Complete'),'#', ['onclick'=>"var openWin = window.open('".$this->Url->build(['controller' => 'Tasks','action'=>'edit', $task->id]."', '_blank', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,status=1,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=500,height=500');  return false;")]);` but I still get the same error

Comment: Is the error really on that line? Because it looks fine.

Comment: @GregSchmidt yeap... If I remove this line I dont get any error

Comment: Ah, you're closing the `()` for the `build` call at the wrong spot: `echo $this->Html->link(__('Complete'),'#', ['onclick'=>"var openWin = window.open('".$this->Url->build(['controller' => 'Tasks','action'=>'edit', $task->id])."', '_blank', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,status=1,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=500,height=500'); return false;"]);`

Comment: @GregSchmidt damn! you are right! thank you very much :)